# Laravel collection nested group by get different field count

Tags: laravel, collections, group-by

There is data as below.

```
"2017-08-13": [
     {
      "cancelledByDriver": 0,
      "busy": 0,
      "cancelledByRider": 0,
      "acceptedByDriver": 1,
      "requestDate": "2017-08-12T21:03:29.754Z"
     },
     {
      "cancelledByDriver": 0,
      "busy": 0,
      "cancelledByRider": 0,
      "acceptedByDriver": 1,
      "requestDate": "2017-08-12T21:08:28.244Z"
     }
],
"2017-08-14": [],
"2017-08-15": [],
"2017-08-18": [],
"2017-08-20": [],
"2017-08-21": [],
"2017-08-22": [],
"2017-08-23": [],
"2017-08-24": [],
"2017-08-25": []
```

I want to print the number of values in fields 1 in each date.So in a date how many cancelledByDriver, busy, canceledByRider and acceptedByDriver (value = 1).

Example:

```
"2017-08-13": [
     {
      "cancelledByDriver": 0,
      "busy": 0,
      "cancelledByRider": 0,
      "acceptedByDriver": 2,
     }
]
```

My Code:

```
$days = $tripRequests->groupBy(function($item) {
                 return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($item['requestDate']));
            })->map(function ($item, $key) {
                return collect($item);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you solved the question or not. But I have same question about this. Finally I found answer according to Laravel's Collection guides.

```
$days = $tripRequests->groupBy(function($item) {
    return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($item['requestDate']));
})->map(function ($item) {
    return $item->sum('cancelledByDriver') ;
});
```

First, the method `groupBy()` is able to group a collection by given keys, that's what you are correctly doing. Then with the method `map()` allows you to re-mapping the collection objects by walking through the each items which associated with date, such as `2017-08-13`. What you need to do is call `sum()` in order to sum the `cancelledByDriver` up.

You will get a new collection with the sum of `cancelledByDriver` which `group by`-ed by the date.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sum